# Simple ajax request doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run simple ajax request, however, it doesnt send the request on IE.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    dataType: "text",
    timeout: 100
}).done(function(str) {
    $.globalEval(str);
});
```

Looking at the console, no errors and warnings. What is the correct way to run this on IE ?

Comment: Just IE? You're making a cross-domain request, so it shouldn't work. And why the `$.globalEval()`?

Comment: But on that case, it should give access denied warning in the console. There is nothing in the console. I am trying to fetch script, instead of using getscript function. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it just failing in IE?

Comment: @user198989 : By IE, which version(s) do you mean ?

Comment: Is your page hosted from your filesystem? Sometimes that causes weirdness with XHR requests.

Comment: The html file is local, the remote url is remote.